# How do I set a nodejs timeout with arrow notation?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, timeout

I am running with node v9.4.0.  In my test suite, how do I set a timeout using the arrow notation.  The below

```
describe('Test Stratum client[callbacks]', () => {
  this.timeout(5000);

  // Test for onConnect getting called
  it('onConnect', (done) => {
```

is causing the error

```
  _this.timeout(5000);
        ^

TypeError: _this.timeout is not a function
```

What is the proper syntax I can use to set the timeout without changing my "describe" line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the rest of the thing in a function and use setTimeout

```
describe('Test Stratum client[callbacks]', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Test for onConnect getting called
    it('onConnect', (done) => {
      //The rest of your code, etc etc
    });
  //blah blah blah
  }, 5000);
```

**ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

There is no timeout in Node.js or in JavaScript. However, you can use a workaround provided you are working in an async context:

```
const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
describe('Test Stratum client[callbacks]', async () => {
  await timeout(5000);
  //etc etc
```

Notice the `async` before `() => {` in the second line

Comment: Thank you @zevee.  I'm a little confused about how to use your code.  So I should change my "describe" line to "describe('Test Stratum client[callbacks]', async () => {"?  Then within that describe line, add "await" and then wrap each of my tests in a "setTimeout" block?

Comment: @satish no. Those were two options. The first one is preferable - wrap your tests in a setTimeout. Elaborated in answer